# Using Async task for calling user defined method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an app where I am loading images from gallery. I saw my GUI freezing a little bit and a message saying "Skipped 53 frames. Your app might be doing huge work in its main thread" something like that. Upon a little bit of research I found that it is a common issue and can be resolved using Async task etc. I have defined a method in my main activity and I am calling that method at the very beginning of my activity, that method must be doing a lot of work. I want to call that method in an Async task or on a parallel thread which will run parallel to my main thread and until it is finished I want to display a message box with the text "processing...." on my GUI. How can I achieve this. I am not passing any arguments to the method in my method call nor I am returning anything from that method.

Comment: Are you asking how to display a dialog box or how to create a thread to do work off the main gui thread? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to create a thread to do work off the main thread and until it finishes execution I want to show the dialog box. I am completely unaware of how to create a parallel thread or create an Async task for a background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use RxJava if you are using Java and Coroutines if you are using Kotlin they are the most optimal solutions at present. But if you still want to use an Async task here is the way.

create an inner class like this,

```
   private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<null, null, null> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
     super.onPreExecute();
     //show progress bar or any 
     thing you want to do before starting the process
  }
  @Override
  protected void doInBackground() {
     //your code that gets the images from gallery
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute() {
     super.onPostExecute();
     // use this callback for if you want to stop showing the progress bar  or  anything that  you want to do after the executing your code in Backgroud
  }
```

}
}

then call this by doing this whenever you want to execute your code,

```
AsyncTaskExample asyncTask=new AsyncTaskExample();
        asyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nitin. I will try it and get back or you.

Comment: Update : Thank you again Nitin. It worked for me. I am hereby accepting the answer.